# Modify the element of a json that is inside a list

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart

I hope you can please help me, In my project I am creating a simple list ***"List listArticulosAdd = [ ];"*** where i put this map of a json that im decoding from a request https:

```
mapArticuleCode = {
      "articleCode": "HC57533",
      "descriptionOne": "FLAT SCREWDRIVER BOX",
      "descriptionTwo": "FLAT SCREWDRIVER BOX",
      "requestAmount": "1", 
      "unitPrice": "59.99",
      "applyTax": "0.16",
      "um": "PZ",
      "precio": "60.15"
    };
```

I want to create a method where if I capture the same product more than once, the ***"requestAmount"*** is modified by increasing the value instead of being added back to the list. I know i have to validate that the product exists in the list, and then modify de data i want. I tried with this code from a few others answers, but nothing happens. I wonder if I miss something. This is the method:

```
if (listArticulosAdd.contains(mapArticuloCode)) {
      setState(() {
        listArticulosAdd.remove(mapArticuloCode);
        int requestAmount =
            int.parse(mapArticuloCode["requestAmount"]);
        requestAmount++;
        mapArticuloCode["requestAmount"] = requestAmount.toString();
        listArticulosAdd.add(mapArticuloCode);
      });
    } else {
      listArticulosAdd.add(mapArticuloCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list method `contains` does not work as you expect since in Dart by default two `Objects` compare equal only if they are the same. Two maps are two  different objects even if they contain the same entries.

In my view, your approach could be improved. For example, an article should be an object that overrides (see below) `hashCode` and the operator `==` (or extends [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable)). I am assuming that the `articleCode` is unique for each article.

```
class Article{
  Article({
    required this.code,
    required this.description,
    required this.requestAmount,
    required this.unitPrice,
    required this.tax,
  });
  final String code;
  final String description;
  int requestAmount;
  final double unitPrice;
  final double tax;

  double get precio => unitPrice + tax;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Article(code: $code, description: $description, '
        '   requestAmount: $requestAmount, unitPrice: $unitPrice, tax: $tax)';
  }
  
  /// Articles with the same code have the same hashCode.
  @override
  int get hashCode => runtimeType.hashCode ^ code.hashCode;
  
  /// Two articles are equal if they have the same code.
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    other is Article && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && code == other.code;  
}

void main() {
  final article = Article(
    code: "HC57533",
    description: "tool box",
    requestAmount: 1,
    unitPrice: 59.99,
    tax: 0.16,
  );
    
  // It makes more sense to store already processed articles in a set.
  final articles = <Article>{article};

  if (articles.contains(article)) {
    article.requestAmount++;
  } else {
    articles.add(article);
  }

  print('articles: $articles');
  print('article: $article');
}
```

```
$ dart main.dart
articles: {Article(code: HC57533, description: tool box,    
  requestAmount: 2, unitPrice: 59.99, tax: 0.16)}

article: Article(code: HC57533, description: tool box,    
           requestAmount: 2, unitPrice: 59.99, tax: 0.16)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually you help me a lot with the use of a model. It worked.